# Как при сравнении версий 1.10.1>1.9.11 получить True?

Tags: python

Есть ли в питоне функция позволяющие работать со строками версий, сравнивать их на больше меньше и т.п.? Например нужно чтобы здесь результатом было True, а в таком виде получается False

```
'1.10.1' > '1.9.11'
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/2574080/10941639.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11887762/how-do-i-compare-version-numbers-in-python

Answer (score 3, accepted):

использовать модуль `packaging`

```py
>>> from packaging import version
>>> version.parse("1.10.1") > version.parse("1.9.11")    
True
```

Модуль следует стандарту определенному в [PEP 440](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0440/).

[Документация по модулю](https://packaging.pypa.io/en/latest/version.html#packaging.version.parse)

Данный модуль является сторонней утилитой, но скорей всего будет включен из коробки.

Если нет то установить:

```
pip install packaging
```

Answer (score 4):

Если не хочется использовать сторонние модули и строки версий состоят только из чисел, то можно их сконвертировать, например, в кортежи чисел, и сравнивать уже их.

```
def version(v):
    return tuple(map(int, v.split('.')))

print( version('1.10.1') > version('1.9.11') )   # => True
```